# How to join two RDDs by a key?

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

```
animals_population_file = sc.textFile("input/myFile1.txt")
animals_place_file = sc.textFile("input/myFile2.txt")
```

animals_population_file:

```
Dogs, 5
Cats, 6
```

animals_place_file:

```
Dogs, Italy
Cats, Italy
Dogs, Spain
```

Now I want to join `animals_population_file` and `animals_place_file` using the type of animals as a key.
The result should be this one:

```
Dogs, [Italy, Spain, 5]
Cats, [Italy, 6]
```

I tried `joined = animals_population_file.join(animals_place_file)`, but I don't know how to define the key. Also, when I run `joined.collect()`, it gives me an error:

```
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o247.collect.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 21.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 21.0 (TID 29, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 101, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 96, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 236, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1807, in <lambda>
    map_values_fn = lambda (k, v): (k, f(v))
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: @zero323: I tried solutions provided in the mentioned thread. However, my problem is that I don't know how to point the key in this code df1.join(df2, df1.k == df2.k, joinType='inner'). Also, if I just do df1.join(df2), then collect() gives an error. It is not explained in the pointed thread.

Comment: What you've shown above is an exact content of your files?

Comment: @zero323: Exact content: RDD1 =  [u'Surreal_Games',
 u'269',
 u'Hourly_Games',
 u'428',
 u'Hot_Talking',
 u'747',
 u'Almost_Sports',
 u'350']
 and another RDD2 = [ u'Loud_Games',
 u'BAT',
 u'Cold_Talking',
 u'DEF',
 u'Surreal_Sports',
 u'XYZ',
 u'Hourly_Sports',
 u'CAB',
 u'Hot_Talking',
 u'MAN',
 u'Almost_Cooking',
 u'BAT']

Comment: No internal tuples or lists? Like  `[(u'Surreal_Games', u'269'), ...]`.

Comment: @zero323: Yes, what I putted is the exact copy-paste from RDD1.collect() and RDD2.collect()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95854/discussion-between-zero323-and-klausos-klausos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have PairRdd when you run textFile (basing on your rdds content from comment).
To make joins, you need the PairRDD however. 
So turn your inputs into pairRDDs

```
val rdd1 = sc.textFile("input/myFile1.txt")
val rdd2 = sc.textFile("input/myFile2.txt")

val data1 = rdd1.map(line => line.split(",").map(elem => elem.trim))
val data2 = rdd2.map(line => line.split(",").map(elem => elem.trim))

val pairRdd1 = data1.map(r => (r(0), r))  /** zero index is the animal type which is the key in file 1*/
val pairRdd2 = data2.map(r => (r(0), r))  /** zero index is the animal type which is the key in file 2 as well */

val joined = pairRdd1.join(pairRdd2)

val local = joined.collect()
local.foreach{case (k, v) => {
  print(k + " : ")
  println(v._1.mkString("|") + "|" + v._2.mkString("|"))
}}
```